# Alternatives to NtQueryInformationProcess to get commandline

Tags: windows, windows-7, device-driver, minifilter

Hello I am using **[NtQueryInformationProcess()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684280%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to retrieve the command line of current process** (via the RTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS in the PEB returned by NtQueryInformationProcess()) on Windows 7.

But the problem is this **The NtQueryInformationProcess function and the structures that it returns are** internal to the operating system and **subject to change from one release of Windows to another**

So Please suggest some **alternatives for the same to maintain the compatibility of application**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For current process it is easy (in user mode), just use [GetCommandLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683156%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). For a different process, you have to go outside the Win32 API:

WMI: [Win32_Process.CommandLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394372.aspx)

See also: [The Old New Thing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/02/23/9440784.aspx)

Comment: suggest something for KernelMode